# How to reference azure network security ID in a module in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

I'm not sure how to reference an azure network security group in a module. I created a module that I can reuse for any VM I create which works to an extent except I'm not sure how to assign the network security group ID to it. The below is an example (slightly amended, I don't have it on me) that is very close to what I have and is based on.

main.tf at root

```
module "vm1" {
source = "/modules/vm/"
NSG = ????
}
```

tfvars

```
nic_name = apache_vm_nic
location = West Europe
........
```

modules/vm/main.tf

```
.........

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "myterraformnic" {
name                = "var.nic_name"
location            = "var.location"
resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name}"
network_security_group_id = { WHAT DO I PUT HERE? }

ip_configuration {
    name                          = "myNicConfiguration"
    subnet_id                     = "${azurerm_subnet.myterraformsubnet.id}"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "dynamic"
    public_ip_address_id          = "${azurerm_public_ip.myterraformpublicip.id}"
}
}


resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "apache-nsg" {
name                = "myNetworkSecurityGroup"
location            = "eastus"
resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name}"

security_rule {
    name                       = "SSH"
    priority                   = 1001
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "22"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
}
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "nginx-nsg" {
name                = "myNetworkSecurityGroup"
location            = "eastus"
resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name}"

security_rule {
    name                       = "SSH"
    priority                   = 1001
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "22"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
}
}
```

in the module/main.tf file under network_security_group_id, I can't exactly put ${azurerm_network_security_group.apache-nsg.id} or ${azurerm_network_security_group.nginx-nsg.id}. So what can I put so I can reuse this module for all VMs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't quite clear to me but I am going to assume you want to create a generic network security group that you want to assign to multiple instances of your VM module.

If you want to pass the ID of a security group from `main.tf at root`, you'd do this:
Create a network security group resource outside your module, e.g. inside `main.tf at root`, just like you created a few inside your VM module (for Apache and Nginx), so that `main.tf at root` looks like this:

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "some_generic_vm_nsg" {
  ....
}

module "vm1" {
  source = "/modules/vm/"
  NSG = "${azurerm_network_security_group.some_generic_vm_nsg.id}"
}
```

Note that we are now passing the ID of the nsg to your VM module instance.
However, your VM module has not declared the `NSG` variable yet. So create the file `modules/vm/variables.tf` and put this in it:

```
variable "NSG" {
  type = "string"
}
```

And inside your module, `network_security_group_id = { WHAT DO I PUT HERE? }` becomes:

```
network_security_group_id = "${var.NSG}"
```

This way, you can assign the same network security group to multiple VM module instances.

You can [study this documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html) for more elaborate information.

Comment: Feel free to mark my answer as the correct answer ;-)